# MVC SelectList SelectValues

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need an extention for converting ToSelectList a list of items (strings or ints)

I found this:

```
        public static SelectList ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
                            string dataValueField, string dataTextField, string selectedValue)
    {
        return new SelectList(collection, dataValueField, dataTextField, selectedValue);
    }
```

but this doesn't handle multiple selected values. 
I tried with this:

```
        public static SelectList ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
                    string dataValueField, string dataTextField, IEnumerable<T> selectedValues)
    {
        var list = new SelectList(collection, dataValueField, dataTextField, selectedValues);
        return list;
    }
```

but it doesn't work.
please help!

Comment: 12 questions now; still not a single accepted answer or vote, despite getting many helpful, often elaborate, answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it but try this:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T>      collection,
         string              dataValueField, 
         string              dataTextField,          
         IEnumerable<string> selectedValues)
{
    var list = new SelectList(collection, dataValueField, dataTextField);
    foreach (var item in list.Items)
    {
        if (selectedValues.Contains(item.Value)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```